# Same Protocol defined in multiple class

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, delegates

Is it possible to define a same protocol with different methods in different classes?

Ex:
   In classA.h

```
  @protocol ME_DELEGATE <NSObject>

  @required

  -(void)doThis;

  @end
```

In classB.h

```
@protocol ME_DELEGATE <NSObject>

@required

-(void)doThat;

@end
```

Am I doing it right?

Comment: Why would you do this? Why not have two protocols with two different names?

Comment: I'm creating a static library where each class (5 NSObject classes totally) has its own delegate protocols. When I integrate into project I just want to add one protocol to call all the methods in different classes.

Comment: make all of them optional

Comment: As @aguiarpgc said, put all of the delegate methods in one protocol and make them optional.  Gotta agree with rmaddy though and say that it sounds like a much better design would have multiple protocols, each with the appropriate methods defined.

Comment: I see so is there a way that I can call multiple protocol through a single import instead?

Answer (score 1):

@Siddharthan Asokan

You can have the same protocol in two different classes and the system will generate a warning "Duplicate protocol definition of 'protocolName' is ignored" (with the default settings)

You can make it work if you declare the protocol methods as @required or @optional.

Also, If you want to have 2 different objects being the delegates for the same protocol, then as already suggested, you need to have the protocol methods defined as @optional... I have tested and it works....   The trickier part is to get the reference to the objects to set the second delegate properly

I added an exercise to show how it works both ways.... Same protocol in two classes and then 2 different objects being the delegates of the same protocol. It also shows how to have 2 delegates to the same class, in the same protocol.

https://github.com/eharo2/ProtocolTest

Given that the protocols are based in the message passing paradigm, with the proper object reference and method implementation, you can do pretty much what you want.

I hope it helps... e

Comment: Thanks for explaination.